# My program gives segmentation fault in openSUSE

Tags: c++, linux

I have a laptop in which I've installed openSUSE 13.2 a month ago. When I try to run this C++ program to print shortest path, I get a segmentation fault. On the other hand, my code works perfectly on my computer on which Ubuntu is installed.

Here is the output I get in Ubuntu...

```
rohan@Symantha:~/Dropbox/cprog/Arrayss/2D$ uname -a
Linux Symantha 3.13.0-53-generic #89-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 20 10:34:28 UTC 2015 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
rohan@Symantha:~/Dropbox/cprog/Arrayss/2D$ g++ 16.cpp 
rohan@Symantha:~/Dropbox/cprog/Arrayss/2D$ ./a.out 
Enter total rows : 4
Enter total cols : 4
Enter array ->
1 0 0 0
1 1 1 0
0 1 1 0
1 1 1 1
Input Ok ..
Enter source row: 0
Enter source col: 0
Enter destination row: 3
Enter destination col: 3
Shortest Path -->>
path :  (0, 0) ->  (1, 0) ->  (1, 1) ->  (1, 2) ->  (2, 2) ->  (3, 2) ->  (3, 3)
```

But in openSUSE, I get this...

```
rohan@linux-zdor:~/Dropbox/cprog/Arrayss/2D> uname -a
Linux linux-zdor.site 3.16.7-21-desktop #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Apr 14 07:11:37 UTC 2015 (93c1539) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
rohan@linux-zdor:~/Dropbox/cprog/Arrayss/2D> g++ 16.cpp 
rohan@linux-zdor:~/Dropbox/cprog/Arrayss/2D> ./a.out 
Enter total rows : 4
Enter total cols : 4
Enter array ->
1 0 0 0
1 1 1 0
0 1 1 0
1 1 1 1
Input Ok ..
Enter source row: 0
Enter source col: 0
Enter destination row: 3
Enter destination col: 3
Shortest Path -->>
Segmentation fault
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code?
Here is my code:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzLbrlYg9GyXd3E4WnFWc3lGVUk/view?usp=sharing

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;

#define MAXROW 10
#define MAXCOL 10

class Cell {
public:
  int row;
  int col;
  Cell() { }
  Cell(int rr, int cc) : row(rr), col(cc) { }
  bool operator==(const Cell& cc) {
    if(row == cc.row && col == cc.col)
      return true;
    else 
      return false;
  }
};

class Path {
  int row[MAXROW*MAXROW];
  int col[MAXCOL*MAXCOL];
  int size;
public:
  Path() : size(0) { }
  Path(Path& pp) {
    size = pp.size;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      row[i] = pp.row[i];
      col[i] = pp.col[i];
    }
  }
  Path& operator=(const Path& pp) {
    size = pp.size;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      row[i] = pp.row[i];
      col[i] = pp.col[i];
    }
  }
  int length() {
    return size;
  }
  void setSize(int ss) {
    size = ss;
  }
  void insert(int rr, int cc) {
    row[size] = rr;
    col[size] = cc;
    size++;
  }
  void print() {
    int i = 0;
    cout << "path : ";
    while(i < size) {
      cout << " (" << row[i] << ", "
           << col[i] << ") ";
      if(i < size-1)
        cout << "-> ";
      i++;
    }
    cout << endl;
  }
  bool searchCell(Cell c) {
    int i = 0;
    while(i < size) {  
      if(row[i] == c.row && col[i] == c.col)
        return true;
      i++;
    }
    return false;
  }
  Cell start() {
    return Cell(row[0], col[0]);
  }
  Cell end() {
    if(size > 0)
      return Cell(row[size-1], col[size-1]);
    else
      return Cell(-1, -1);
  }
};


Path shortestPath(int arr[][MAXCOL], int, int, Cell, Cell, Path);
void inputArr(int arr[][MAXCOL], int mR, int mC);


int main() {
  int arr[10][10], mR, mC, r, c;
  Path p;
  cout << "Enter total rows : ";
  cin >> mR;
  cout << "Enter total cols : ";
  cin >> mC;
  cout << "Enter array ->\n";
  inputArr(arr, mR, mC);
  cout << "Input Ok ..\n";
  cout << "Enter source row: ";
  cin >> r;
  cout << "Enter source col: ";
  cin >> c;
  Cell source(r, c);
  cout << "Enter destination row: ";
  cin >> r;
  cout << "Enter destination col: ";
  cin >> c;
  Cell destination(r, c);
  cout << "Shortest Path -->>\n";
  p = shortestPath(arr, mR, mC, source, destination, p);  
  p.print();
  return 0;
}

Path shortestPath(int arr[][MAXCOL], int mR, int mC, Cell current, Cell target, Path p) {
  int i = current.row;
  int j = current.col;
  Path p_array[4];
  if(arr[i][j] == 0 || i == mR || j == mC || i < 0 || j < 0 
     || p.searchCell(current)) {
    p.setSize(0);
    return p;
  }
  p.insert(i, j);
  if(i == target.row  &&  j == target.col) 
    return p;  
  else {
    // Since there are four possible directions
    p_array[0] = shortestPath(arr, mR, mC, Cell(i, j+1), target, p);
    p_array[1] = shortestPath(arr, mR, mC, Cell(i+1, j), target, p);
    p_array[2] = shortestPath(arr, mR, mC, Cell(i, j-1), target, p);
    p_array[3] = shortestPath(arr, mR, mC, Cell(i-1, j), target, p);
    int minIndex, minSize, i;
    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      if(p_array[i].length() != 0 && p_array[i].end() == target ) {
        minIndex = i;
        minSize = p_array[i].length();
        break;
      }
    }    
    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      if(p_array[i].length() < minSize && p_array[i].end() == target) {
        minIndex = i;
        minSize = p_array[i].length();
      }
    }
    return p_array[minIndex];
  }
}

void inputArr(int arr[][MAXCOL], int mR, int mC) {
  int i, j;
  for(i = 0; i < mR; i++)
    for(j = 0; j < mC; j++)
      cin >> arr[i][j];
}
```

Comment: run debugger, check where it throws

Comment: That's not how Stackoverflow works. Read [ask] for information on how to ask a good question.

Comment: I'm sorry, this is my first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your validation mis-ordered in your `shortestPath` function:

```
if (arr[i][j] == 0 || i == mR || j == mC || i < 0 || j < 0 
    || p.searchCell(current)) {
```

You access the array out of bounds before checking whether the bounds are valid.  This is undefined behaviour, and different systems can behave differently in the presence of undefined behaviour (so crash and appearing to work are both valid responses to invoking undefined behaviour).

Rewrite the condition to check that the indices are OK before accessing the array.

```
if (i == mR || j == mC || i < 0 || j < 0 || arr[i][j] == 0
    || p.searchCell(current)) {
```

This may not be the only problem; it is one problem.

---

When I take your code verbatim from the question and compile it, I get compilation warnings (errors since I use `-Werror` to convert warnings into errors).

```
$ g++ -O3 -g -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror 16.cpp -o 16
16.cpp: In member function ‘Path& Path::operator=(const Path&)’:
16.cpp:41:3: error: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Werror=return-type]
   }
   ^
16.cpp: In function ‘Path shortestPath(int (*)[10], int, int, Cell, Cell, Path)’:
16.cpp:143:40: error: ‘minSize’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Werror=maybe-uninitialized]
       if(p_array[i].length() < minSize && p_array[i].end() == target) {
                                        ^
16.cpp:29:15: error: ‘minIndex’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Werror=maybe-uninitialized]
     size = pp.size;
               ^
16.cpp:134:9: note: ‘minIndex’ was declared here
     int minIndex, minSize, i;
         ^
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
$
```

Those are serious problems and may account for your code going haywire.  Certainly, you need to fix those before it is worth doing anything else.

I note that you have:

```
class Path {
    int row[MAXROW*MAXROW];
    int col[MAXCOL*MAXCOL];
```

At the moment, `MAXROW == MAXCOL` so there are the same number of elements in `row` and `col`, but if the numbers were different, you might not be able to store all the members of the path in one or the other of the two arrays.  Not so good.  The arrays should be the same size unconditionally.  Also, in `main()`, you define:

```
 int arr[10][10], …
```

which should, of course, be:

```
int arr[MAXROW][MAXCOL], …
```

With minimal fixups, setting `minIndex = -1` and `minSize = -1` in `shortestPath()`, and adding `return *this;` to the assignment operator, and then adding diagnostic printing at the end of `shortestPath()`:

```
Path shortestPath(int arr[][MAXCOL], int mR, int mC, Cell current, Cell target, Path p) {
  int i = current.row;
  int j = current.col;
  Path p_array[4];
  cerr << "-->> shortestPath(" << i << "," << j << ")\n";
  //if(arr[i][j] == 0 || i == mR || j == mC || i < 0 || j < 0
  if (i == mR || j == mC || i < 0 || j < 0 || arr[i][j] == 0 || p.searchCell(current)) {
    p.setSize(0);
    cerr << "<<-- shortestPath() - 1\n";
    return p;
  }
  p.insert(i, j);
  if (i == target.row && j == target.col)
  {
    cerr << "<<-- shortestPath() - 2\n";
    return p;
  }
  else {
    // Since there are four possible directions
    p_array[0] = shortestPath(arr, mR, mC, Cell(i, j+1), target, p);
    p_array[1] = shortestPath(arr, mR, mC, Cell(i+1, j), target, p);
    p_array[2] = shortestPath(arr, mR, mC, Cell(i, j-1), target, p);
    p_array[3] = shortestPath(arr, mR, mC, Cell(i-1, j), target, p);
    int minIndex = -1, minSize = -1, i;
    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      if(p_array[i].length() != 0 && p_array[i].end() == target ) {
        minIndex = i;
        minSize = p_array[i].length();
        cerr << "1: minIndex: " << minIndex << ", minSize: " << minSize << "\n";
        break;
      }
    }
    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      if(p_array[i].length() < minSize && p_array[i].end() == target) {
        minIndex = i;
        minSize = p_array[i].length();
        cerr << "2: minIndex: " << minIndex << ", minSize: " << minSize << "\n";
      }
    }
    cerr << "3: minIndex: " << minIndex << "\n";
    cerr << "<<-- shortestPath() - 3\n";
    return p_array[minIndex];
  }
}
```

and running it, part of the output is:

```
-->> shortestPath(2,0)
<<-- shortestPath() - 1
3: minIndex: -1
<<-- shortestPath() - 3
```

Oops: accessing and returning `p_array[-1]` is not a good idea.  You have subscripts out of control — small wonder things go haywire.  You need to meditate on the code is not setting `minIndex` to a value other than `-1` and what to do about it.

Comment: No, it's still not working. But thanks for pointing out this problem.

Comment: When i run gdb i get this:->Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000004011f4 in Path::Path (this=0x7fffffff01e0, pp=...) at 16.cpp:29
29          size = pp.size;